# R: find corpus document by ID-tag and set an additional tag

Tags: r, tags, corpus, tm

Want to write tags for documents being inside a corpus. The tags are stored outside the corpus in a dataframe with the specific unique document-IDs.

The challenge:
(1) take each ID from the dataframe,
(2) find the coresponding document inside the corpus,
(3) set the tag from the dataframe to the corpus document with the specific ID.

```
library("tm")
someID <- paste(letters[1:15], 16:30, sep="")
someTag <- sample(c("a","x","g","h","e"), 15, replace=TRUE)

data(crude) # a corpus with 20 docs
meta(crude, type="local", tag="someID") <- someID  # adding some additional IDs to the corpus

mydf <- data.frame(cbind(someTag, someID))  # Creating a dataframe with similar IDs
mydf <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf)),]  # permutation of elements (rows)
rownames(mydf) <- 1:15  # overwriting the rownames

############################################
# doesn't work - my try - pseudocode

for (i in 1:nrow(mydf)){
          meta(crude[which(crude$someID==mydf$someID[i])], tag="someTag", type="local") <- mydf$someTag[i]
    }

############################################
# How the data looks like:

mydf
# R output:
> mydf
   someTag someID
1        h    l27
2        x    g22
3        h    d19
4        a    e20
5        h    i24
6        x    j25
7        h    o30
8        x    n29
9        e    h23
10       x    m28
11       h    k26
12       e    c18
13       a    a16
14       e    b17
15       x    f21

meta(crude[1], type="local")
# R output:
> meta(crude[1], type="local")
Available meta data pairs are:
  Author       : 
  DateTimeStamp: 1987-02-26 17:00:56
  Description  : 
  Heading      : DIAMOND SHAMROCK (DIA) CUTS CRUDE PRICES
  ID           : 127
  Language     : en
  Origin       : Reuters-21578 XML
User-defined local meta data pairs are:
$TOPICS
[1] "YES"

$LEWISSPLIT
[1] "TRAIN"

$CGISPLIT
[1] "TRAINING-SET"

$OLDID
[1] "5670"

$Topics
[1] "crude"

$Places
[1] "usa"

$People
character(0)

$Orgs
character(0)

$Exchanges
character(0)

$someID
[1] "a16"
```

Thank you for any help (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ?meta

```
meta(crude, type="local", tag="someID") <- someID
```

will assign the meta data tag someID at the individual document level.  What you want is to create a tagging at the collection level.  For this, you want to manipulate the `DMetaData` attribute of the corpus crude.  You can do this as:

```
meta(crude, type="indexed", tag="someID") <- someID
```

but I find it much easier to use the access

```
DMetaData(crude)$someID  <- someID
```

(this at least works for corpora of type VCorpus).  With this adjustment:

```
library("tm")
someID <- paste(letters[1:15], 16:30, sep="")
someTag <- sample(c("a","x","g","h","e"), 15, replace=TRUE)

data(crude) # a corpus with 20 docs
# Need to be sure to allocate full tag and id set.
DMetaData(crude)$someID <- c(someID,rep(NA,5))
DMetaData(crude)$someTag <- rep(NA,20)

mydf <- data.frame(cbind(someTag, someID), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  # Creating a dataframe with similar IDs
mydf <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf)),]  # permutation of elements (rows)
rownames(mydf) <- 1:15  # overwriting the rownames

for (i in 1:nrow(mydf)){
      DMetaData(crude)$someTag[DMetaData(crude)$someID==mydf$someID[i]]<- mydf$someTag[i]
    }
```

Result:

```
> DMetaData(crude)
   MetaID someID someTag  
1       0    a16       a
2       0    b17       h
3       0    c18       g
4       0    d19       a
5       0    e20       e
6       0    f21       a
7       0    g22       x
8       0    h23       g
9       0    i24       h
10      0    j25       e
11      0    k26       x
12      0    l27       a
13      0    m28       a
14      0    n29       h
15      0    o30       a
16      0   <NA>    <NA>
17      0   <NA>    <NA>
18      0   <NA>    <NA>
19      0   <NA>    <NA>
20      0   <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice :) It works. Only `someTag` has to be declared previously as `as.character(mydf$someTag[i])`. Can I edit your post? Wold add also the whole `> DMetaData(crude)` output with the new letter tags.

Comment: Good catch.  I fixed this.

Comment: Thank you! Very elegant solution! Have a nice day! (: